# Filtering with HMM

Tags: hidden-markov-model, filter

I want to use HMM for filtering, i.e. to find $p(x_t|y_{1:t})$.

I see that the forward algorithm calculates the forward variable as a joint probability; $\alpha_t(i) = p(y_{1:t},x_t=S_i|\lambda)$, 
meaning joint of observations so far and the current state is $S_i$, given HMM parameters $\lambda$.

To find $p(x_t|y_{1:t})$, it looks fine to sum all alphas at time t to find the marginal $p(y_{1:t}|\lambda) = \sum_{i=1}^{N}\alpha_t(i)$.

Now, if I normalize $\alpha_t(i)$ for each of N possible states with this marginal, the resulting distribution should be $p(x_t|y_{1:t})$.

Does that sound fine?

Comment: I assume the hidden state is $x$ and the emitted variable is $y$... yes, this is ok.